# Notification Builder can't accept "this" as replacement for "context", why?

Tags: android, notifications, this, android-context, builder

How do I resolve this problem? If I replace it with `this`. It created more errors on the builder. How do I solve it?

All codes in the java class. In this case, the functionality revolves around the `onStartCommand`.

```
 public class MyNotificationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnStartCommand()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationintent = new Intent(this, Reminder_2.class);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationintent, 0);
        int icon=R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when=System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingintent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
        builder.setWhen(when);
        builder.setTicker("Notification");
        builder.setContentTitle("Title");
        builder.setContentText("Content");
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notificationmanager.notify(033, notification);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// try this
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
```

Comment: This is the closest answer. Thanks. But I was able to figure it out. I needed to use NotificationCompat.Builder in this case.                   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)  
  .setContentIntent(pendingintent)
  .setAutoCancel(true)
  .setSmallIcon(icon)
  .setWhen(when)...                                   This code works, but then again, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`

Comment: "getApplicationContext()" didn't work. Just like "this", it created the same problem.

Comment: Which instance of `this` exactly is causing the issue?  I just realized you've got several `this`s in your code.

Comment: Anything related to the builder contains error. This lines contain errors after using getApplicationContext();                                         Notification.Builder builder = new Builder( getApplicationContext());
  builder.setContentIntent(pendingintent);
  builder.setAutoCancel(true);
  builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
  builder.setWhen(when);
  builder.setTicker("Notification");
  builder.setContentTitle("Title");
  builder.setContentText("Content");
  Notification notification = builder.build();

Answer (score 0):

I think you've used the wrong Builder class, please try below,

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .build();
```

Reference: 
[android developer site, Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)

Hope can help you.